# R Matrix remove rows of 0

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (large one) and I want to iterate through the rows and if that row has all 0s for every column from the second column to the end (35th) then remove that row. This is a matrix of 0s and 1s for each event in rows, and features in the columns.

```
for (i 1:nrow(myMatrix) {
   keep = False
   for (k 1:ncol(myMatrix) {
      if (mymatrix[i,k] == 1) {
          keep = True
      }
   if (keep == False) {
      row.remove()
    }
}
```

something like above,... 
thx

Comment: Loops are dreadfully slow in R, compared to vectorized operations. In you case, index `mat` with a vector of TRUE/FALSE specifying which rows to keep and discard, as in Frank's solution, to get faster, shorter and more readable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
m[rowSums(m[,-1]) != 0,]
```

Comment: This worked! except the above statement prints to screen, and obviously if one wants to set it to a new matrix one must use: m_clean <- m[rowSums(m[,-1]) != 0,]